# Mapping a String to an array of ints - Java

Tags: java, arrays, static

How do I map a String to a statically defined array of ints? I tried

```
private static Map<String, int[]> map = new HashMap<String, int[]>();
static {
    map.put("foo", {5, 1, 3, 2});
    map.put("bar", {2, 7, 8});
}
```

which tells me that {5, 1, 3, 2} is illegal.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to call the array's constructor before you initialize the content.

```
map.put("foo", new int[]{5, 1, 3, 2});
```

Answer (score 5):

Try

```
private static Map<String, int[]> map = new HashMap<String, int[]>();
static {
    map.put("foo", new int[]{5, 1, 3, 2});
    map.put("bar", new int[]{2, 7, 8});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the map will never be changed, you could use [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) lib:

```
private static ImmutableMap<String, int[]> immutaleMap =
    ImmutableMap.of("foo", new int[]{5, 1, 3, 2},
                    "bar", new int[]{2, 7, 8});
```